# How can I timeout a web-call to retrieve a JSON feed?

Tags: json, httpclient

I'm making a call using the HttpClient to retrieve a JSON feed. I want to set a time out for this call in case it takes too long. How can I do that?

Comment: as a my understanding you want set the timeout for web-service call ?

Comment: Which time are u talking about response aur request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpClient` has a `Timeout` property. Set that to timeout you want and handle the `TimeoutException` to do specific things on the timeout.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    response = await client.GetAsync(url);
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    // handle the timeout, e.g. return false
    return false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the other errors, e.g. throw it
    throw (ex);
}
```